# Сравнение значений из разных таблиц

Tags: php

Есть страница с информацией про различные музыкальные группы. Есть кнопка перехода к картинкам с этой группой. Нужно выводить из базы картинки только с этой группой. Я хочу сравнить, мол, если поле "Название" в бд совпадает со значением поля "Группа", то выводятся картинки.

```
<?
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
$db="syte";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die;
mysql_select_db($db);
 echo'<section>   <ul id="gallery"> <li id="fullPreview"></li>';
$result=mysql_query ("Select `bands_image`.*, `bands`.`Название` from `bands_image`,`bands` where `bands_image`.`Группа`=`bands`.`Название`");
while ($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
if ($myrow['Путь'] != ""&&file_exists("image/".$myrow['Путь'])) 
{ 
$img='image/'.$myrow['Путь']; 
$img_mw=240; 
$img_mh=150; 

} 
if ($myrow['Группа']==$myrow['Название']){

echo  '
            <li>
                <a href="'.$img.'" width="'.$img_mw.'" height="'.$img_mh.'"/></a>
                <img data-original="'.$img.'" width="'.$img_mw.'" height="'.$img_mh.'" src="'.$img.'" width="'.$img_mw.'" height="'.$img_mh.'" alt="Фото 1" />

                <div class="overLayer"></div>
                <div class="infoLayer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h2>'.$myrow['Группа'].'</h2>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>'.$myrow['Описание'].'</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="projectInfo">
                    Полное описание изображения
                </div>
            </li>
';}}
 echo'</ul>
</section>';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Первый скрин таблицы с общей информацией про группы, второй скрин таблица, где хранятся сами картинки.

Comment: так join'ом объедините и сразу будет поле, либо null, либо ссылка на картинку

Comment: inner join ????

Comment: я думаю, что left join

Comment: Оно выводит просто все картинки которые есть. Или я что-то не так сделал.

Comment: примерно так должно быть: `select t1.*, t2.путь from t1 left join t2 on t1.название = t2.группа`

Comment: Ошибка подключения к бд.

Comment: это врядли из-за лефтжойна :)

Comment: Оно пишет, что поля bands не существует.